# which theme is this?

Tags: themes

Could anyone help me finding which WP theme has been used in this site?

http://www.laquilacittaaperta.it/

I only have found concerning a DM theme but I really haven't been able to find it anywhere

thank you
Mari0

Comment: Close-voted as *too localized*. This question would be far more generally useful if it were phrased as "*how to determine what Theme a current site is using*" - but even then, it might be too trivial for WPSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a modified version of DM's CircloSquero theme.  DM doesn't seem to have it available anymore, but Theme Forest has it for download [here](http://www.wikmag.com/circlosquero-theme-by-themeforest.html).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can just look in `style.css` to get the theme name.  In this case, the theme is named "dm-dm," which isn't very helpful.

Based on that, though, my best guess is that this is a custom theme built specifically for that site.